# How to show 4 items per row in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I have a few items that need to be shown as 4 items per row like in Amazon. Below image is of Amazon.

This is what I want:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

**Code:**

```
function loadBooksTable(){
axios.get(baseUrlLocal + '/book/info')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
    console.log(response.data)
    response.data.forEach(request => {
        i=i+1;

        html = '<tr>'
        html +='<td align="center">'+request.ISBN+'</br>' ;
        html +=request.BookName+'</br>' ;
        html +=request.Author+'</br>' ;

        html +=request.PricePerDay + '</br>';
        html +='<img id="thumb" style="width:80px;height:80px" src="./images/'+ request.ISBN +'.png"/>' + '</br>';
        html +=isRented(request.Rented) + '</br>';
       '</td>' ;
        html +='</tr>';
       $('#view-all-books tbody').append(html);
    });
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
});
}
```

Comment: ok, its a typing mistake. Edited the question. Please answer if you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spawn a new `tr` (table row) for each `td`, so every `td` is on a new line. Close the closing `</td>` after the loop. Also give the `tr` width of `25%`

```
 axios.get(baseUrlLocal + '/book/info')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response)
    console.log(response.data)
    html = ''
    response.data.forEach(request => {
        i=i+1;
        html +='<div class="item">'+request.ISBN+'</br>' ;
        html +=request.BookName+'</br>' ;
        html +=request.Author+'</br>' ;

        html +=request.PricePerDay + '</br>';
        html +='<img id="thumb" style="width:80px;height:80px" src="./images/'+ request.ISBN +'.png"/>' + '</br>';
        html +=isRented(request.Rented) + '</br>';
       '</div>' ;

    });
    $('#view-all-books tbody').append(html);
})
```

CSS:

```
.item{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This gives everything in 1 row

Comment: @Taplar that was true, made an edit. Honestly I would rather do that with `div`s

Comment: ok small modification to be done i=i+1; moved below the condition. Worked

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need to support older versions of IE, one very simple approach would be CSS grid:

```css
#thegrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr)
}
```

```html
<div id="thegrid">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
</div>
```

Or you could go with the less elegant but more broadly supported "just use percentage widths":

```css
#thegrid {
  width: 100%
}

#thegrid div {
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="thegrid">
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
  <div>Item</div>
</div>
```

Either approach saves you from having to hardcode the number of columns into your HTML structure, making it much easier to change the number of columns responsively.